# how to compare two specific elements from two different Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, use-effect

i have two states , state A and state B the first one contain an object witch is postuledby that contain the id of user and in state B i have the user id .
so i wanna know how to compare postuledby with user id
this is my try but it did not work cause it give me all the users and didn't compare :

```
const PostuledBy = ({ offrr, dev }) => {
  const [listdev , setListdev]=useState([]);


useEffect(()=>{
setListdev(dev
  ?.filter((el, index) => {
    return offrr.postuledby.filter((ell) => ell._id === el._id);
  }))
},[])
return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
function compareByInnerId(AArray, BArray){
    return AArray.filter(el=>BArray.includes(el.id))
}
```

I didn't really got the whole postuledby naming thing but the code above expects the `BArray` to have *only the ids*. something like: `[1,32,4]` and AArray to have the whole object. ex: `[{name:"blah", id:1}, {name:"mlah", id:32}]`

Comment: postuledby is an object in A array witch contain the id of the user . Thank you I will try it

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 arrays, one is ids for control and other containing objects.

```
const ids = ["1", "2", "7", "75"];

const objArr = [
    { id: "1", name: "mike" },
    { id: "3", name: "jesse" },
    { id: "75", name: "Den" },
    { id: "89", name: "Jen" }
  ];
```

with a simple filter you can find the objects containing in ids array:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setResult(objArr.filter((obj) => ids.some((id) => id === obj.id)));
  }, []);
```

[here is a simple example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-pine-pjq20o?file=/src/App.js)